# AJAX not Posting date to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

AJAX is sending a selected date - ('articleDate') - to a PHP document where it is then used within an SQL statement, however, I am getting an undefined error in my code when I run the PHP, on the line where I declare:

```
$date = $_POST['articleDate'];
```

Meaning that the value is not being posted to PHP.
I have checked the code and it seems to be working fine semantically. Is there a separate method for posting 'date' values within AJAX?

The PHP code works when there is no AJAX being used, and the form is being Posted via method - with the cue of a Submit Button.

HTML `<body>` code:

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!--wrapper start-->
<!--include navbar-->
<?php include 'include/navbar.php';?>

<div class="container" id="content"><!--container start-->
    <div class="jumbotron"><!--jumbotron start-->
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row" id="date">
                <form>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="articleDate" onchange="viewArticle(this.value)">
                </form>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div id="article">

           </div>
        </div> <!--Row end-->
    </div><!--Jumbotron End-->
    <?php require 'include/footer.php';?>
</div> <!--container end-->
```

Javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("articleDate").value="";
}
function viewArticle()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../pages/include/viewArticle.php",
        data: {
            Date: document.getElementById("articleDate").value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("article").innerHTML=response; 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('article not sent');
         },
    }); 
}
```

PHP code (date initiation is where the error is(undefined variable):

```
#Get date
$date = $_POST['articleDate'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Article WHERE articleDate=? ORDER BY articleDate desc");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date);
if($date !== "")
{
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $data = $stmt->get_result();

        #Check number of rows statement selects

        if($data->num_rows > 0)
        {
            #print data
            while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
                #create div
                echo ' <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="articleDiv">';
                echo "<img class='img-responsive' id='articleImage' src=".$row['articleThumbnail'].">";  
                echo '<h3><a href="article.php?id='.$row['articleId'].'">'.$row['articleHeadline'].'</a></h3>';
                echo '<p>',$row['articleSummary']," ",'</p>';
                echo '<div class="row" id="rowDetails">';
                echo '<p>' , $row['articleDate']," | " , $row['articleTopic'],'</p>';
                echo '</div>';            
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>No articles exist on this date</p>";
        }
    }
    #$stmt->close();
    #$conn->close();   
}
else{
    echo "Date not working";
}
```

*Undefined varibale* = $date

Comment: You are posting `Date`, but receiving it as `articleDate` -  that won't work. Either change `Date` to `articleDate` in your JS or `$_POST['articleDate']` to `$_POST['Date']` in your php.

Comment: in php you shoud do $_POST['Date']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the PHP you're getting the posted argument by name `articleDate` :

```
$_POST['articleDate']
```

When you're sending `Date` instead.

You've two choices :

1. You could change the argument name in your JS like :

   ```
   data: {
      articleDate: document.getElementById("articleDate").value
   },
   ```
2. Or you could change it in your PHP code like :

   ```
   $_POST['Date']
   ```